# Make PHPmailer a "more secure app" for Gmail

Tags: security, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

What security can we implement in PHPmailer to make it a more secure app for Gmail? https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255
I am using PHPmailer to send emails via Gmail. PS: I don't want to enable "access for less secure apps" here: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps, I want to make the app more secure.

Answer (score 18):

Gmail has started imposing a new authentication mechanism that substitutes SMTP athentication for OAuth2-based authorisation. The docs on their changes can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/xoauth2_protocol).

This doens't really improve security much because ultimately you still need to submit your username and password over SSL at some point (the very mechanism that google deems insecure) to authenticate to get an OAuth token, which is exactly as secure as existing SMTP auth systems.

As yet, PHPMailer does not support this new mechanism - PRs welcome! You will need an OAuth2 class, such as [this one](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/7700-PHP-Authorize-and-access-APIs-using-OAuth.html), and perhaps make use of [this code example](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/42011.html).

In the mean time, you *do* have to "enable access for less secure apps", and you should set `SMTPSecure = 'tls'` and `Port = 587` and use normal auth to connect using PHPMailer.

## Update

PHPMailer supports Gmail's XOAUTH2 authentication as of version 5.2.11. See [this guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-Gmail-with-XOAUTH2). It's being expanded in version 6.0 to support other services too.

Comment: Now Gmail doesn't allow users to use SMTP without "allowing access form less secure apps".
I am looking for a way to make the app more secure and bypass that setting.

Comment: Ah, OK - Google has started enforcing their OAuth 2 policy. Frankly it's a fairly feeble idea - esentially they are saying that they trust themselves more than they trust you to access your own data (one of the reasons I don't use gmail), and they have chosen to ignore all the available security enhancements to SMTP and IMAP in favour of their non-standard approach. In other words, no, there is no alternative to switching on that option.

Comment: Another interpretation might be that they don't like the security that TLS offers, so they decided to break SMTP and IMAP instead.

Comment: You can probably couple sending email with an oAuth token - [this oauth class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/7700-PHP-Authorize-and-access-APIs-using-OAuth.html) is well maintained - but I don't know how you'd make the two work together. Google is saying that logging into your google account with id and password over SSL is more secure than doing the same with SMTP, which makes no sense at all.

Comment: I am just trying to check if a Gmail username and password are correct, not trying to send emails, so I just send a SMTP connection request to see if the credentials are valid. Can you help implement the OAuth class?

Comment: Sorry, no. You'll need to read google's docs. There may be example code with that class.

Comment: "This doens't really improve security much because ultimately you still need to submit your username and password over SSL at some point" — But the web application doesn't need to know the password, so if the server hosting the PHP is compromised then your primary GMail password is still safe.

Comment: Since the OAuth tokens are bearer tokens, they are the same thing as an id and password, at least as far as accessing/using gmail is concerned. It’s true that they may not give you access to other Google services, but for many gmail is the only one they use, so there is no practical difference. If the host is compromised, someone can send (and probably read) email from you using those credentials.