# Secure PHP SendMail

Tags: php

So this is my first post, I try to tell what my issue's are.
I have bought a domain name that I want to sell.

So I code a simple HTML website with some CSS stuff.
OK. I also have a form in my HTML, that contains this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Amount" name="amount">
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" required name="name">
<input type="text" placeholder="Email Address" required name="email">
<div class="validation">
    <button class="btn" name="submit">Send request</button>

$email_to = "email@email.com";
$amount = $_POST["amount"];
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$email_subject = "Domeiname";
$headers = "From: " . $email . "\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: " . $email . "\n";

ini_set("sendmail", $email);
$sent = mail($email_to, $email_subject, $amount, $headers, "-f" .$email);
if ($sent)
{
    header("Location: https:mywebsite.com");
} else {
    echo "There has been an error sending your comments. Please try later.";
}l
```

It's working and I receive emails. So my question is, is it safe? Is it vulnerable to hackers?

(I also receive in my Gmail, that this email can be spam/not from me).

Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: Found another issue: In my email, I only receive the "amount" status and not the "name + email".

Comment: This one should help- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28125138/make-phpmailer-a-more-secure-app-for-gmail

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of libraries that will take all the hard work of securely sending email from you - such as [swiftmailer](https://packagist.org/packages/swiftmailer/swiftmailer).

```
<?php
require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';

// Sendmail
$transport = Swift_SendmailTransport::newInstance('/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs');

// Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

// Create a message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Wonderful Subject')
  ->setFrom(array('john@doe.com' => 'John Doe'))
  ->setTo(array('receiver@domain.org', 'other@domain.org' => 'A name'))
  ->setBody('Here is the message itself')
  ;

// Send the message
$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

You may also find it very valuable to sign up for a service such as Mailgun and also setup your code to use their servers to actually send the email (there are libraries would setup as a 'transport' to send the message to them via HTTP, and then they email it to the final destination). There are a number of such 'ESP' (Email Service Providers), and many offer a substantial free-tier, so it won't cost you anything for even thousands of emails per month.

Comment: This answer would be much more useful to the OP if it were to deal with the elements from his $_POST. It neglects to mention mail header injection at all or the reason why swift mailer would be any more secure.

Answer (score -1):

It looks as though you are sending an E-mail when a form is submitted. This is perfectly secure; there is no way a hacker could manipulate **who** the E-mail gets sent to; PHP is server-side code. Thus, `$email_to = "email@email.com";` **cannot** get manipulated from the form itself, as it is hard-coded into your PHP.

Obviously, the `$_POST` data variables get passed through from the form, so their contents **can** be manipulated by the form -- though this is required in order for you to be able to retrieve the visitor's name and E-mail address.

PHPMailer did have a recent vulnerability in it, where an attacker could breach your website by entering a certain 'From' E-mail address, but this has since been patched. You still need to allow the user to enter their E-mail address, or you won't know who to reply to.

However, a user would still be able to create additional headers based on you not validating that the 'From' address is an actual valid E-mail address. You should validate this, and only send the E-mail if it is found to be valid:

```
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
  $sent = mail($email_to, $email_subject, $amount, $headers, "-f" .$email);
}
```

Note that you're also not actually doing anything with the `$name` variable. Assuming you're trying to make it display the person's name in the 'FROM' field in the E-mail, you need to pass it as:

```
$headers = "From: " . $name . " <" . $email . ">\n";
```

So that it gets rendered as `From: Person <email@email.com>`.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you, Obsidan Age. I'm just new in this developing + with security.
I really tried to do my best. I also thought it was secure, because I don't have the option to add attachments.

Than you again, I have learned some from you today! :)

Comment: It is not entirely secure. There is no verification of the user email string, so the user can easily add some extra headers to the email header.

Comment: Ahh yes; you'll definitely want to sanitise against that. Just validating the E-mail should prevent that happening. I've just updated my answer to cover this.

Comment: Thank you guys, you all are amazing.

EDIT: Found another issue: In my email, I only receive the "amount" status and not the "name + email".

Edit 2: I added the code, above in your text. Thank you. Now I can sleep better. :)

Comment: This form is vulnerable to email header injection. An attacker can CC or replace existing headers very easily and construct spam email of arbitrary content.

Comment: @S.Imp -- `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` ensures that the user only enters a valid E-mail address. `"\n"` is stripped. Please explain how they can construct arbitrary headers after validation?

Comment: @RedaBenz -- You're not receiving `name` because you're not actually passing that to `mail()`. I think you're looking for `$headers = "From: " . $name . " <" . $email . ">\n";` :)

Comment: Than you Obsidian, I think I fixed.
Only when I press "submit" it sends me to site.com/sendmail.php 

I do something wrong.. :(

Code in HTML: <form action="sendmail.php" method="POST" class="contact-form">

Comment: The form action should direct you to the PHP page that has your code to submit the E-mail on it. I'm **assuming** your mail code is on `sendmail.php`? The code there will trigger the E-mail, and if the E-mail gets sent successfully, it will redirect to `https:mywebsite.com` (which should be `https://mywebsite.com`). If the sending of the mail fails, it will display an error message.

Comment: @ObsidianAge The headers can easily be injected by putting a line break or two in $_POST["email"] which is not validated at all before being inserted into $headers.

Comment: @ObsidianAge I would add that $email is fed into ini_set("sendmail", $email); and also along with the -f flag at the very end. It's as if the email script was designed to be exploited. Makes me wonder if this question might be for a homework assignment.

Comment: @S.Imp -- Not validated? What do you think `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` does? Granted, I didn't move the headers into the conditional, so the headers get assigned before the validation, but the E-mail only sends after validation, making it impossible to send an E-mail with an address that uses line-breaks.

Comment: @ObsidianAge I'm well aware of filter_var's behavior. You seem to not realize that your code snippet validates $email_to (which comes from a scalar string) and not $email, which comes from POST and goes not only into $headers but also the last param of the mail command. Look at your own code & *realize* you don't validate any post data at all with filter_var.

Comment: @S.Imp -- Ahh, true, I did indeed mean to use `filter_var($email...`. I've corrected that now; that was a slight oversight.